# How do I read a text file into a string variable in Python starting at the second line?

Tags: python, string, list, python-2.7, readfile

I use the following code segment to read a file in python

```
file = open("test.txt", "rb")
data=file.readlines()[1:]
file.close
print data
```

However, I need to read the entire file (apart from the first line) as a string into the variable `data`.

As it is, when my files contents are `test test test`, my variable contains the list ['testtesttest'].

How do I read the file into a string?

I am using python 2.7 on Windows 7.

Comment: is `test test test` exists on a single line?

Comment: "How do I read the file into a list?" You have already done so: "my variable contains the list ['testtesttest']" So what's the problem?

Comment: Also, is that your real code? It gives me a SyntaxError.

Comment: It looks like I/O that's been halfway converted to using the `with..as` construct.

Comment: "read the entire file (apart from the first line) as a string" / "read the file into a list" -- those don't seem compatible.

Comment: Yest, test test test is on a  single line.

Comment: Sorry, I did not realize that I put list instead of string. I have updated and fixed my question.

Comment: Could someone please tell me what is still wrong with my question instead of just downvoting it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is pretty simple. You just need to use a `with ... as` construct like this, read from lines 2 onward, and then join the returned list into a string. In this particular instance, I'm using `""` as a join delimiter, but you can use whatever you like.

```
with open("/path/to/myfile.txt", "rb") as myfile:
     data_to_read = "".join(myfile.readlines()[1:])
     ...
```

The advantage of using a `with ... as` construct is that the file is explicitly closed, and you don't need to call `myfile.close()`.

Comment: The `with` construct is certainly desirable, but I don't see how it makes the OP's code do anything different.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I think the OP was confused for some reason. His question was asking how to read file contents, apart from the first line, and that's what the above example does.

Comment: I updated and fixed my question. i need the variable to contain a string. Also, the problem with `readlines()` is that itgives me a list instead of a string.

Comment: Please ignore the `strip()` statement. It was not supposed to be part of the code.

Comment: @PseudonymEnigma Do you want newlines after each line of the file in the string?

Comment: No. Just a string on one line.

Comment: @PseudonymEnigma Alright, I've edited my answer,